# jQuery tablesorter disable last header

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using tablesorter for my tables, and now I want that always the last header is disabled from sorting.

**I have tried this:**

```
 $(".sorter")
 .tablesorter({widgets: ['zebra'], headers:{0:{sorter:false}, -1:{sorter:false}}})          
 .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager"), positionFixed: false, size : 5 });
```

But that does not work... does someone know a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a valid config to specify -1, try this

```
var $sorterTable = $(".sorter");

var tablesorterConfig = { widgets: ['zebra'], headers:{ 0:{sorter:false} } };

tablesorterConfig.headers[$sorterTable.find("thead th").length - 1] = { sorter:false };


$sorterTable
.tablesorter(tablesorterConfig)          
.tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager"), positionFixed: false, size : 5 });
```

Comment: Still not working... i have edit my first post with all the code i use , maybe this helps you.